# Limits of SiriKit?

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit

I'm thinking a lot about how Siri could improve the UX of my App.

I'm coding an app dedicated to fitness, to log your workouts and your personal records.

I would like to let the user use Siri to use features of my App, but I don't really understand if it's possible or not. I read the documentation but it's not very clear for me, I don't know if Siri is limited to "start / stop / pause / resume a workout" or if we can do more.

( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/workouts )

> I would like to add things like that:
>
> - "*Hey Siri, **what's my personal record for deadlift***?"
> - "*Hey Siri, **log 230 reps for my workout of the day***"
> - "*Hey Siri, **what is the workout of the day?***"

Could you tell me if it's possible to do that? Is it possible to **connect Siri with your app and your database / functions**?

Comment: I don’t have experience in it personally but in iOS 12 Apple is introducing Siri Shortcuts. Siri is a lot more flexible and can make so many more requests using it. You’d have to download Xcode 10 and iOS 12 beta to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

The possible actions that Siri can initiate (the "intents") are pre-defined by Apple. From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit:

> SiriKit defines the types of requests—known as intents—that users can
>   make. Related intents are grouped into domains to make it clear which
>   intents you might support in your app. For example, the messages
>   domain has intents for sending messages, searching for messages, and
>   marking messages as read or unread.

Comment: Alright so yes, I can't do what I would like to do with SiriKit. I should look at siriShortcut probably